# Limit number of Mist.exe processes

Tags: mist, command-line

After a recent update I noticed Mist starts six mist.exe process instances, presumably one for each physical CPU core in my machine.

I would like to limit this to just one. Is there a command-line argument I can use to do so?

The reason is that I've found Geth / Mist to be major resource hogs on my PC (particularly I/O). I use Process Hacker to reduce the Priority and I/O Priority of each process, which works like a charm. But having to do this on seven different processes each time I start the software is a pain.

Here are the commands I'm using to launch the software:

```
start "geth" "C:\Program Files\Mist\nodes\geth\win-x64\geth.exe" --datadir "L:\Ethereum" --cache=512
start "Mist" "C:\Program Files\Mist\Mist.exe" --datadir L:\Ethereum
```

Comment: The resource usage seemed to get a little better lately (either from improvements to the client-side codebase or the nature of recent data on chain).  I've been using Process Hacker to lower the Priority and I/O Priority, although I noticed the software is sensitive to this at startup (sometimes it prevents pipe connection to geth?).  Still would like a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it appears that it sets [GOMAXPROCS](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#GOMAXPROCS) to the number of CPU cores [automatically](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=GOMAXPROCS&type=). If you're willing to manually recompile geth every time there's a new version, you could alter the source code to set GOMAXPROCS to only 1. But otherwise, there doesn't seem to be a way to set this manually.

Comment: Thanks.  If I was going to crack open the source code I think I would go the full route and submit a pull request with a `--cores=n` switch (or whatever label is appropriate).  On the face of it, seems like it would be a fairly easy thing to add (and update any corresponding docs).  In the meantime I've got Process Hacker 2 automatically setting the priorities for all process sharing the same name (or parent ID or something) as soon as they launch, so it's not annoying me quite as much anymore.